# Check whether there is a user on the console/interactive session from a .NET Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am writing a service that performs a certain operation that only makes sense if a user is interactively logged onto the console session (that is, if somebody is physically at the machine). I have found that, on Windows 7, `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId` returns the session ID of the console session even if no user is logged onto it but there is a user logged on with Remote Desktop.

There are some processes running under the console session, even though nobody has logged on at the physical console since the computer was rebooted. However, Task Manager does not list that session ID in the Users tab.

How do I check whether there is an interactive logon in the console session?

Answer (score -2):

```
Boolean Environment.UserInteractive
```

Answered here: [How to know if a Windows session is an interactive one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910381/how-to-know-if-a-windows-session-is-an-interactive-one)

Comment: Sorry, that returns whether the service is running interactive, which is always "no."